# How to get the permissions right for /dev/raw1394

Tags: linux, permissions, udev

I recently upgraded one of my ubuntu machines to Karmic and I'm having trouble getting the permissions of /dev/raw1394 set to 0666.

They only thing this machine is used for is recording audio from a firepod which uses /dev/raw1394 via jackd and there are no other FireWire devices connected, so security around this device is not really an issue.

If I run as root, everything works as expected, but I have some folks that run the recorder that I don't want to have root access.  However, I can't figure out which lines setup the perms

I've tied this:

```
/etc/udev/permissions.d/raw1394.rules:raw1394:root:root:0666
```

And I have this setup (default install)

```
/lib/udev/rules.d/75-persistent-net-generator.rules:SUBSYSTEMS=="ieee1394", ENV{COMMENT}="Firewire device $attr{host_id})"
/lib/udev/rules.d/75-cd-aliases-generator.rules:# the "path" of usb/ieee1394 devices changes frequently, use "id"
/lib/udev/rules.d/75-cd-aliases-generator.rules:ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="block", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb|ieee1394", ENV{ID_CDROM}=="?*", ENV{GENERATED}!="?*", \
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage-tape.rules:KERNEL=="st*[0-9]|nst*[0-9]", ATTRS{ieee1394_id}=="?*", ENV{ID_SERIAL}="$attr{ieee1394_id}", ENV{ID_BUS}="ieee1394"
/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:# FireWire (deprecated dv1394 and video1394 drivers)
/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:KERNEL=="dv1394-[0-9]*",        NAME="dv1394/%n", GROUP="video"
/lib/udev/rules.d/50-udev-default.rules:KERNEL=="video1394-[0-9]*",     NAME="video1394/%n", GROUP="video"
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:KERNEL=="sd*[!0-9]|sr*", ATTRS{ieee1394_id}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/ieee1394-$attr{ieee1394_id}"
/lib/udev/rules.d/60-persistent-storage.rules:KERNEL=="sd*[0-9]", ATTRS{ieee1394_id}=="?*", SYMLINK+="disk/by-id/ieee1394-$attr{ieee1394_id}-part%n"
```

And I find these lines in /var/log/syslog

```
Apr 30 09:11:30 record kernel: [    3.284010] ieee1394: Node added: ID:BUS[0-00:1023]  GUID[000a9200c7062266]
Apr 30 09:11:30 record kernel: [    3.284195] ieee1394: Host added: ID:BUS[0-01:1023]  GUID[00d0035600a97b9f]
Apr 30 09:11:30 record kernel: [   18.372791] ieee1394: raw1394: /dev/raw1394 device initialized
```

What I can't figure out, is which line actually creates that raw1394 device in the first place.

How do you get /dev/raw1394 to have permissions 0666?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Firewire

Short story is I created /etc/udev/rules.d/raw1394.rules and put this line in it:

```
KERNEL=="raw1394", GROUP="video", MODE="0666"
```